# base_link to world transform

Tags: ros, frame, geometry, kdl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

In a recent conversion from diamondback to electric, I noticed that my tf state publisher had stopped converting from 'base_link' frame to 'world' frame. With no changes in my own tf publisher or robot model between ROS versions, I can only assume something changed in some ROS package(s). Upon further inspection, the geometry stack changed quite a bit, with kdl moving out completely. I can't seem to pin down the exact change that's causing the problem. Can anyone help me resolve this problem and get back my 'world' frame?

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27553/base_link-to-world-transform/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my state publisher, where I publish my other transforms with RobotStatePublisher::publishTransforms(...), I had to also add RobotStatePublisher::publishFixedTransforms(). Between diamondback and electric, RobotStatePublisher::publishTransforms(...) began to only publish transforms for moving joints. See the functions at line 78 and line 100 in [robot_state_publisher.cpp](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/robot_state_publisher/html/robot__state__publisher_8cpp_source.html) (ignore the incorrect print statement for the second function). In order to publish fixed joint transforms, you must call RobotStatePublisher::publishFixedTransforms().

This problem is also referenced in this post: [Why does robot_state_publisher skip publishing fixed joints](http://answers.ros.org/question/11662/why-does-robot_state_publisher-skip-publishing).

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1